# DiskSpace quota exception when running spark action in oozie

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run a spark action in oozie. My spark job fails with the below error :

```
The DiskSpace quota of /user/nidhin is exceeded: quota = 10737418240 B = 10 GB but diskspace consumed = 10973426088 B = 10.22 GB
```

I added the staging dir property in my oozie workflow and pointed to a HDFS directory other than home which has TBs of space , even then i get the same error.

```
<action name="CheckErrors" cred="hcat">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>JobName</name>
            <class>com.nidhin.util.CheckErrorsRaw
            </class>
            <jar>${processor_jar}</jar>
            <spark-opts>--queue=${queue_name}
                --num-executors 0
                --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
                --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
                --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=${hdfs_data_base_dir}
            </spark-opts>
            <arg>${load_dt}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End" />
        <error to="Kill" />
    </action>
```

${hdfs_data_base_dir} is /tenants/proj/ directory in HDFS and has TBs worth of space in it.

When i look into the spark jobtracker UI , the property is properly reflected.

```
spark.yarn.stagingDir   hdfs://tenants/proj/
```

**How do fix this error and point to the above mentioned stagingDir ?**

Comment: Its due to HDFS replication. For example you are trying to write 500GB data and HDFS has a a replication of 3. Then total space required is 500 * 3 = 1500 GB. If you available space less in HDFS than this  requirement it would fail with this exception. What is size of data that you are trying to write ?

Comment: From the error the data size is ~ 10.22 GB , so considering the replication of 3 its about 30GB but the staging directory that i pointed is having atleast 500 TB space. So I am not sure if its replication factor issue.

Comment: Can you check your directory quota with this command:  **hadoop fs -count -q -h -v /user/nidhin**

Comment: @Constantine : The main objective here is not to use the user hdfs home directory, but some other hdfs directory.

Comment: I think there is space quota set for user directories. You can read in detail here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html